# how to resolve branch.io android manifest linking error

Tags: android, android-manifest, branch.io

Implementation of Branch IO on Android build is failing with the following error.

```
 Execution failed for task ':app:processDevDebugResources'.
[1] > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
[1]    > Android resource linking failed

AAPT: error: resource string/xxx.test-app.link (aka com.xxxx.xxx.xxx.app:string/xxx.test-app.link) not found.
```

The AndroidManifest.xml file looks like this:

```
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="@string/xxx.test-app.link" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="@string/xxx-alternate.test-app.lin" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace  com.android.support:support-v4:+ with com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0 in  platform/android directory.
And  add the following code to the platforms/android/app/build.gradle and platforms/android/build.gradle files:

```
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy {
    force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
}}
```

I think it will help you

Answer (score 0):

`<intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_view_http_gizmos">`

You should establish a label for your intent-filter.